# R fails to round 126.5

Tags: r, rounding

R fails to round the number "126.5". I discovered this by accident.

```
round(125.5) # = 126, correct
round(126.5) # = 126, wrong
round(127.5) # = 128, correct
```

I expect that the output of `round(126.5)` to be `127`, but the actual output is `126`. R rounds other numbers correctly (see above). Does anybody know what the problem is and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation `?round` -

> Note that for rounding off a 5, the IEC 60559 standard is expected to
>   be used, ‘go to the even digit’. Therefore round(0.5) is 0 and
>   round(-1.5) is -2. However, this is dependent on OS services and on
>   representation error (since e.g. 0.15 is not represented exactly, the
>   rounding rule applies to the represented number and not to the printed
>   number, and so round(0.15, 1) could be either 0.1 or 0.2).

Comment: The question "Round up from .5" answers my question. Thanks for the hint!